# How to obtain user date time settings in android

Tags: android, calendar

I have a Calendar object, and i know how to format it using android.text.format()
How can i get the phone settings for date and time to format the object to format set by the user. Like 24 hour clock , mmm dd yyyy...

Comment: @Paresh Mayani What i ment was the date-time settings set by the user

Comment: What you want to achieve to update date setting or getting date time from setting?

Comment: @user370305 what i want is to display the date and time in seperate textviews, but in the format that is set by the user on his phone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I wanted was to provide the date and time formatted according to the user's preferences and locale, in separate TextViews.

I have done this using static methods in the `DateFormat` class:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()); // Gets system date format
DateFormat timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getApplicationContext()); // Gets system time format

txt1.setText(dateFormat.format(CalendarInstance.getTime())); // format() Returns a string according to the user's preferences (12-hr vs 24-hr) and locale
txt2.setText(timeFormat.format(CalendarInstance.getTime()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, not exactly all the settings (such as 24 vs 12 hour format) selected by the user, but to use the configured locale you can use the [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class.

Comment: [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html), in the same package as DateUtils, contains information about the currently used settings, including 12 vs 24 hour format.

Comment: I tried this but i get a force close error                        DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()); df.format(<calendar instance>);